# USB to COM, how does the RS-232 interperate data?

Tags: usb, hid, rfid

If I had a RFID reader that sends a bunch of keystrokes through USB like a HID, how would the COM port interperate that if I used a USB to COM converter? What would the COM port see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* see the "keystrokes" from the rfid device.

At the link level, the converter should take care of speed mismatch issues. It does this via an internal buffer or by throttling the sender.

But the [HID protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device#Components_of_the_HID_protocol) is more than simple keystrokes. So either the additional information will be suppressed by the USB-COM converter or it won't be. This issue may also be converter-dependent.

In this sort of HW mashup, the best thing is to try it and see. (And then write a blog post about what you discovered.)

What is your overall goal? What sw are you trying to connect the RFID reader to?

**Added** I agree with @Turbo J's point: most every USB-COM converter acts as a USB device. As such, if you connect them to another USB device, nothing will happen since you're using them "the wrong way around."

You'll need to find a USB/Host to COM converter. The usual name for such things is "computer" -- a used laptop may be your best bet if you want to continue down this road.

Comment: OK, thanks for response. I have already ordered the COM converter. I can write the program myself to receive the data, but I wanted to make sure the data came through how I planned. The program will simply take the data and write it to a file line by line along with a timestamp.

Comment: @Zephni, I hope I didn't steer you in the wrong direction! Check the description of the converter carefully to see whether it acts as a USB host or device....

Comment: Don't worry I had to try it any way, and it was only a couple of £'s. Anyway, the RFID was bought by my boss, and it is chinese and we have no idea about the manufacturer. So I guess that was the first mistake. The USB-COM doesn't even power the thing lol! Alough I have found this awesome library.. http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/ .. Promlem being is i don't understand visual studio very well so I don't even know how to put my project together at the moment..

Comment: Thanks. The USB Host supplies power to the USB Devices, so it sounds like the USB-COM converter is also a USB Device--its mission is to connect a serial device to a computer via USB, not to connect a USB device to a serial port on a computer. There are also cheap plug computers that you could use: See PlugComputer and raspberrypi.org

Answer (score 1):

On USB, a device can only talk to the host.

The RFID reader is a device. The `USB->COM` converter is a device. They cannot talk to each other wihout a host.

Conclusion: If you want the RFID data going out of the COM port, write a program which does that -  by reading the HID data from RFID device and writing to the USB COM port.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing.  COM ports are usually very low speed things (you can usually tweak them up to about 115kbps.  USB ports are (by comparison) incredibly high speed ports.  I think the lowest speed USB is like 1.5mbps.

The more important question is how you are going to make the physical conversion.
You have an RFID reader that has a usb plug on it. Are you going to chop this off and solder a db9 connector on the end, which you are then going to plug into an USB to COM adapter and try to read serial data off the com port?
You are adding in one more step into it that you don't need to (you're taking up an usb port anyway).

Comment: Am I wrong in saying I can use a USB to COM cable? The USB side of the cable can plug directly into the RFID reader.

Comment: I just assumed you meant an usb adapter that plugs into your computer.  You are saying you have a cable that connects to an usb peripheral (in this case the RFID reader) that then has a DB9 female connector capable of connecting to a normal Com port?